# Accessing values from one-to-many relationship in PonyORM

Tags: ponyorm

For a database of games, where one game is called different names by different users, I have two tables, set up as one-to-many:

```
class Game(db.Entity):
    name = Set('Name')
    ...

class Name(db.Entity):
    game = Required(Game)
    name = Required(str)
    ...
```

How can I access the names for a specific game? They come back as "Multiset", which (I think) is a special Counter object, when I do this:

```
games = Game.select()
for g in games:
    names = g.name.name
    print(names)

>>> Multiset({'Sticks And Stones': 1, 'May Break Your Bones': 1 })
```

This also seems pretty ugly to me, I suppose there must be a better way?

Comment: `games = select((g, g.name.names) for g in Game)[:]` I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `to_dict()` method, well documented in PonyORM's [API Reference](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#Entity.to_dict), helps greatly with to-many relationships.

```
 for g in games:
      this_game = g.to_dict(
          with_collections=True,
          related_objects=True,
          exclude=['game_meta', 'statistics']
      )
```

And then access the dict() entries like this: `this_game['name']`